# How to populate div tables and dropdownboxes with JSON and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dropdownbox

I've been trying to populate div tables with dummy JSON data but I cannot seem to do it. What I want to do is display certain data depending of the selection in a dropdownbox. Also I need to create new row with a new dropdownbox when an item is selected. Could you give me some advice of what's the best way to do it. I'm able to create something close to what I need in Angular but I need it in pure JavaScript. Thanks in advance!

[structure of my div tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8nZL.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve], and read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share your code? That will help us understand what behaviour you want and can help better.

Comment: @Rajesh I've included the structure of the div tables. The id's that are included are from my tries to display data which didn't work as I planned. Thanks for the help !

Comment: @danielradst Code not screenshot of code. Something we can debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose in **data** you have json object

```
var data = [
{
  "line": "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.",
  "author": "Brian W. Kernighan",
  "num" : ["1","2","3"]
},
{
  "line": "Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen.",
  "author": "Edward V Berard",
  "num" : ["5","0","15"]
},
{
  "line": "It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law.",
  "author": "Hofstadter's Law",
  "num" : ["15","222","301"]
}];
```

and you want to populate all authors in above json object to table and num into respective dropdown element of table-row. Then following **populateHTML()** function populate object to table and num into respective dropdown element of table-row as shown in below image .[image]

```
function populateHTML(data) {    
    if (typeof(data) == 'object') {
        document.write('<table>');
        for (var i in data) {
            document.write('<tr><td>'+data[i].author+'</td><td><select>');
            for(var j in data[i].num){
                 document.write('<option>' +data[i].num[j]+ '</option>');  
            }
            document.write('</select></td></tr>'); 
        }
        document.write('</tr></table>');
    } else {
        document.write(' => ' + data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following code: You can also check an example here: http://skillcram.com/JS_DivTable.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function populateTable() {    

    var tableData = {
        products : [
            {"id": 100,"name":"Laptop", "qty":1,"status": ["Delivered","Damaged","Missing"]},
            {"id": 200,"name":"Monitor", "qty":2,"status":["Refused","Partial"]}
        ]
    }

    var  tableBody = document.getElementsByClassName("divTableBody");


    for (i in tableData.products){

        tableBody[0].innerHTML += "<div class=\"divTableRow\">  "   +
        "<div class=\"divTableRowCell\">"+ tableData.products[i].id +" </div>  "  +
        "<div class=\"divTableRowCell\">"+ tableData.products[i].name +" </div> " +
        "<div class=\"divTableRowCell\">"+ tableData.products[i].qty +" </div> "+
        "<div class=\"divTableRowCell\">"+ getSelectHTMl(tableData.products[i].status) +

        " </div> "+
        "</div>";

    }


}

function getSelectHTMl(status) {

    selectHTMlStr = "<select> ";

    for (j in status){
        selectHTMlStr +=            
        "<option value=\""+ status[j]+ "\" id=\"itemStatus\" >"+status[j]+ " </option>" ;

    }

    selectHTMlStr += "</select>" ;
    return selectHTMlStr;
}
</script>
```